# How to fix discord.py MongoDB not updating

Tags: python-3.x, database, mongodb, discord.py

My Code:
if userexp > userlevel_threshold:
print("Level Up!")
await self.bot.exp.update_by_id({"_id": message.author.id, "level":  userlevel + 1, "exp": userexp + 1})

It prints "Level Up!" but is does not update anything in the database. No errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
if userexp > userlevel_threshold:
    print('level up')
    updated_level = {
        "level": userlevel+1, 
        "exp": userexp+1
        }
    self.bot.exp.update_one({'_id':f'{message.author.id}'},{'$set':updated_level})
```

You can use [[update_one]](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) function to update the level for a specify user by using this code!
[[other examples]](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mongodb_update.asp)